# hardconnectspersecond and harddisconnectspersecond in performance counter always zero why?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection-pooling, odp.net, performancecounter

We are using oracle performance counter using `Oracle.dataaccess.client` namespace and creating multi instance to set up the performance counter and printing the performance counter values.Each and every time I will open my connection and print the counter values.Sample values are shown below.

```
"HardConnectsPerSecond":0.0,
"HardDisconnectsPerSecond":0.0,
"SoftConnectsPerSecond":0.0,
"SoftDisconnectsPerSecond":0.0,
"NumberOfActiveConnectionPools":2.0,
"NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools":0.0,
"NumberOfActiveConnections":6.0,
"NumberOfFreeConnections":4.0,
"NumberOfPooledConnections":6.0,
"NumberOfNonPooledConnections":0.0,
"NumberOfReclaimedConnections":30.0,
"NumberOfStasisConnections":0.0
```

I always getting `HardConnectsPerSecond` and `HardConnectsPerSecond` as zero.If I create performance counter using `System.data.oracleclient` namespace getting values why?If any one knows please explain me.
Note:for `System.data.oracleclient` I am creating single instance to set up performance counter.

Comment: Are you enabling it in the registry? See the doc for more info.

Comment: @ChristianShay yes i am enabling from registry like this,<configuration>
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
  <settings>
    <add name="PerformanceCounters"
         value="4095"/>
  </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
</configuration>